# GET not working in Weblogic Server

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am trying to learn about Weblogic servers and very new to it. I am trying to do a post the values from an HTML page to a servlet. Here is a sample program that I am trying to run.

TestServelt.java

```
package com.saran;
/* all the imports */
@WebServlet("xy")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
     public TestServlet() { super(); }
     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
     {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            out.println("<h1>Welcome to the world of Http SErvlet</h1>");
            String s=request.getParameter("name");
            out.println("My name is"+ s);
            String s1=request.getParameter("age");
            out.println("My age is"+ s1);
     }
}
```

weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.5/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<wls:weblogic-version>12.1.2</wls:weblogic-version>
<wls:context-root>Temp/xy/</wls:context-root>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

index.html which has a form

```
<form action="/Temp/xy" method="get">
Enter your name<input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
Enter your age<input type="text" name="age"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="clickhere"/>
```

When I enter the name and age and submit it, I get " Error 403- Forbidden The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. "

I tried setting the value of  to true. In this case it just gives the list of files in the project folder but not the expected output. What should I change or where is the error so that I get the expected output which is to print out the values that I enter?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure about it, but it might be related to the fact you don't have a redirection there, e.g.:

> public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
>       {
>      response.setContentType("text/html");
>       ...
>       ...
>       out.println("My age is"+ s1);
>       *response.sendRedirect("/yourserver/response.jsp?result=success");*
>       }

Comment: Is it necessary to have a redirection ? I dont even have a jsp to redirect too. I just want to get values from html and print it.

Comment: Where or how do you want to print them? If you want to print the response without having a JSP (or HTML or whichever), you should use something like: OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream(); 
output.write(...); I believe that something like out.println("...") won't to the trick.

Comment: response.getWriter gives a PrintWriter object which can print out the object in the browser. Though I agree it is said to be a bad practice, it is not necessary for the HTML code to belong to JSP file.